# Dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu. How do I get my disk space back now that I dont want Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu with grub to dual boot with Windows. I just want to remove Ubuntu/Get my disk space back for my windows disk on this system.

Notice here how it stuck an NTFS volume between my Windows partition and the Ubuntu partition. Seems like it could be a bad situation!

[image]

Comment: right click on 825MB NTFS volume and select Extend volume. Then specify the amount that you want to increase the partition size.

Comment: @Vishwa OK. Can I merge the (C:) with those two proceeding volumes though?

Comment: I guess so. but before try that, i'd advice you to take a backup, in case